# Resize picture to 2MB

Tags: c#, javascript, image, image-resizing, resize-image

I am wondering if it is possible to resize a picture so it takes up less space??
If I have a 20MB picture and I upload it. Is it the possible to convert it so it only takes up let us say 2MB... or really just any size smaller than the start one.
And if so... any ideas how?

Comment: What kind of picture? What graphics format are you using currently? BMP? Have you tried to transform it into JPEG (photography)/PNG (abstract)?

Comment: I think that you're probably best off using my [library for server-side image resizing and recoding](http://imageresizing.net). Here's [an example of uploading and re-compressing *properly* during upload](http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/upload-and-resize).

Comment: @ComputerLinguist nice module!

Answer (score 4):

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/27041-How-compress-image.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/245867/reduce-size-of-image-csharp

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/559561-how-compress-jpeg-file-wtih-high-quality

http://isharpnote.com/isharpnote/post/2012/01/13/Compress-JPEG-Image-using-C.aspx

[Compress image in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377438/compress-image-in-net)

http://savotdane.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-compress-resize-image-in-net-c.html

http://geekswithblogs.net/bullpit/archive/2009/04/29/compress-image-files-using-c.aspx

And then there is the second page of google results...
Seriously.

Comment: Please note for the future that a list of links isn't really an answer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Noted. It's just silly that people come and ask others to google stuff for them.

Comment: I agree completely. The correct response is to do any of the following: 1) Down Vote 2) Vote to Close 3) Do nothing. Don't waste your effort posting links. Or, do as the other answer did. This kind of 'answer' tends to get up votes, as you note here... but it also tends to get deleted by mods because it's not really an answer. There's a bit of info in the FAQ about this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll take those in mind.